How to remove @license in _next/static/chunks/pages
I have a facing in _next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js. how to remove comment out for license? there are many that word in anywhere in my source.
enter image description here
enter image description here
react: 18.2.0
react-dom: 18.2.0
next: 13.5.4
webpack: 4.0.0
I install plugin uglifyjs-webpack-plugin9
webpack.config.js
enter image description here
